# XML and Special characters & different closing tags

Tags: html, xml

Ok.. so I have an excel spread sheet. I need to build a schema that will suite the columns within the sheet. But the columns titles contain HTML code. Is there a XML editor that can assist in this or can I do this freehand?

```
<meta name="title" content="Test Page"/>
<meta name="dcterms.title" content="Test Page" />
<meta name="dcterms.creator.CHIN" content="All about my test page..blah blah blah"/>
<meta name="dcterms.creator.org" content="Test Guy"/>
<meta name="dcterms.creator.ind" content="TG"/>
<meta name="dcterms.created" scheme="W3CDTF" content=""/>
<meta name="dcterms.issued" scheme="W3CDTF" content="2010-11-13"/>
<meta name="dcterms.modified" scheme="W3CDTF" content=""/>
<meta name="dcterms.language" scheme="ISO639-2/T" content="eng" />
```

The name of each column is within tags... whats the solution to make tis work.. any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any html code in your column titles... unless your saying that each line is a column name?

Answer (score 1):

If the title, dcterms.* are the tag names, you're in the clear.

XML tag names can contain `.`, just not start with it.

**Edit:** As an alternative, you could tree out:

```
<dcterms>
  <dcterm>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <creator>
      <CHIN>All about my test page..blah blah blah</CHIN>
      <org>Test Guy</org>
      <ind>TG</ind>
    </creator>
    <created>2010-11-13</created>
    <!-- ... -->
  </dcterm>
  <dcterm>
    <!-- ... -->
  </dcterm>
</dcterms>
```

Depending on your setup, this may or may not end up as being easier to parse and, generally, deal with.